# List compiled metrics in a keras model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have loaded a Keras model (or just created it and compiled). How do I access the list of metrics objects with which the model was compiled?
I can access the loss and the optimizer using: `model.loss` and `model.optimizer`.
Therefore, I assumed that I will find the list of metrics in `model.metrics`, but that only returns an empty list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get them before `model.fit()` from the `model.compiled_metrics` attribute, which is a MetricGenerator object created in `model.compile()`. The memory address is the same before and after fitting so I assume it is the same object. This is working with tf 2.6.0.

```
>>> model.compile(metrics=[tf.keras.losses.sparse_categorical_crossentropy])
>>> model.metrics
[]
>>> model.compiled_metrics
<keras.engine.compile_utils.MetricsContainer at 0x7f701c7ed4a8>
>>> model.compiled_metrics._metrics
[<keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy object at 0x7facf8109b00>]
>>> model.fit(x)
...
>>> model.metrics
[<keras.metrics.Mean object at 0x7facf81099e8>, 
<keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy object at 0x7facf8109b00>]
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to run the model for atleast 1 epoch for the metric names to be available:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
x = np.random.uniform(0,1, (37432,512))
y = np.random.randint(0,2, (37432,1))
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy",
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
print(model.metrics_names)
_ = model.fit(x= x, y = y, validation_split=0.2, verbose = 0)
print(model.metrics_names)
```

Output:

```
[]
['loss', 'accuracy']
```

For metric objects:

```
model.metrics[1:]
```

Output:

```
[<tensorflow.python.keras.metrics.MeanMetricWrapper at 0x7fbe702aee50>]
```

Comment: `model.metrics_names` returns list of metrics names and loss names. What I am looking for is the list of metrics objects. In this case, the output I am looking for should be:
`[<tensorflow.python.keras.metrics.Accuracy object at 0x.....>]`

Comment: See the updated answer. First component will be the loss object. The next components will be metric object as specified in compile.